# Integrate Google cloud messaging in iOS app

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

My requirement is to receive push notification From GCM . My API(php) server will send push notification to device based upon the Device Id am sending to my API.

I tried in their developer site. It gives me a sample of sending from device . But android there are so many links how to integrate receiving push notofications in android .

So how can i integrate in iOS . With google cloud messaging .

Comment: y downvote ? . am not able to find any tutorial to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the [Google Cloud Messaging homepage](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), it reads:

> Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you
>   to send data from your server to your users' **Android-powered
>   device**, and also to receive messages from devices on the same
>   connection.

Google Cloud Messaging is for sending push notifications to Android devices, not to iOS devices. In other words, you cannot do what you are trying to do.

Apple offers a similar service called [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) (APNS). You can use APNS to send push notifications to iOS users.

In other words, you PHP server needs to integrate with GCM *and* APNS.

Comment: You can setup GCM to forward to APNs, thus forward to your ios device.

Answer (score 2):

Now GCM supports push notification for both android and ios. Here is the link which can help you to integrate GCM in ios app-

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start